# Gulp.js minifies, uglifies and copies all the files but still the app in the dist folder doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gulp

I am working on a project and it's my first time I have tried gulp for organising my web application.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const cssminify = require('gulp-cssmin');

// Copies html to dist folder
gulp.task('copyHtml', function(){
    return gulp.src('./*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('imgOpt', function(){
    return gulp.src('./images/{**\/*.*,*.*}')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});
gulp.task('minify', function(){
    return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('copyAssets', function(){
    return gulp.src('./assets/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets'));
});

gulp.task('copyJSON', function(){
    return gulp.src(['!package.json', '*.json'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('minifycss', function(){
    return gulp.src('./css/*.css')
    .pipe(cssminify().on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('copyFonts', function(){
    return gulp.src('./fonts/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('default',['copyHtml', 'imgOpt', 'minifycss', 'minify', 'copyAssets', 'copyJSON', 'copyFonts']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./*.html',['copyHtml']);
    gulp.watch(['!package.json', '*.json'],['copyJSON']);
    gulp.watch('./fonts/**/*.*',['copyFonts']);
    gulp.watch('./assets/**/*.*',['copyAssets']);
    gulp.watch('./images/{**\/*.*,*.*}',['imgOpt']);
    gulp.watch('./css/*.css',['minifycss']);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js',['minify']);
});
```

Above is my gulpfile.js. When I process this file by using gulp command in git that works without any error and the 'dist' folder is created but the the project transferred to the dist folder is all messed up and it looks like a lot of code is missing. I am unable to detect the problem.

All my javascript code is in ES5 as the ES6 standards were not acceptable and the there were errors encountered in the process.

Comment: What isn't working? I'd start by temporarily removing all the minifying and uglifying code. Run it plain to get rid of noise.

Comment: I tried to detect as you said. It is working fine if I copy plain css without minification. So it's definitely cssmin that's causing the problem. My problem is not solved but I got a closer look of it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My bad I was using an old plugin to minify css that was being depracated. Now everything is working fine.
Just to clear: gulp-minify-css and gulp-cssmin are older plugins of gulp that are not in use now. Instead for css minification gulp-clean-css is being used.

https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css